# Idiom for creating similar build targets (one option changes)

Tags: build-system, waf

I want one release version and a debug version of the same files.

Right now I have written a python function that creates the two versions. Is there a more idiomatic way, maybe directly supported by waf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, waf use "variants" to manage such things. See §7.2.2 of the [waf book](https://waf.io/book)

Comment: Are you aware of any way to do to modify already created TaskGen objects? In my project, the easiert way would be to add/ remove items to the use-option, which isn't possible in the configuration stage I think.

Comment: @Inkrementator : You're right. The configuration stage is here to manage environments. You can have different env for different variants. In the build stage, you can have a different command for each variant. Then you can change some things during build stage.